# Later version of GEOS on pypi

Tags: python-2.7, pypi, cartopy, geos

I am trying to install GEOS 3.3.3 on my workstation. When I look at pypi (https://pypi.org/search/?q=geos), I only see versions up to 0.2.1. Do I need to install it from somewhere else?

Comment: [Here](https://trac.osgeo.org/geos), I think. Version 3.3.3 is rather old — 2012 year.

Comment: Thank you! These libraries were C++. Can they be used with python? Can I use it python directly, or do I need swig?

Comment: I'm using geos with cartopy.

Comment: I believe they have Python bindings using `swig` right in the archive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are needing to setup GEOS for a python environment, you should check out Anaconda's python distribution environment.  They provide pre-built GEOS for many platforms.   https://anaconda.org/search?q=geos

see https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/

Comment: Thank you! Is anaconda retrieving libraries from somewhere other than pypi?

Comment: anaconda is a separate entity from pypi.  They have an elaborate build system that provides artifacts for people to use.